# Panel slideup of custom size using jqtouch

Tags: web-applications, iphone, jqtouch

I am trying to make a view to slide up using jqtouch. But I want the view to slide up only to half of the phone screen height (The one that appears when we tap bookmark button in safari - iphone). I tried making changes in the css file. But it does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at css animations and don`t use jQtouch. Instead have a div that is designed to animate and reveal itself. Don`t think of it like a different section but more of a pop up. Trying to hack into the JQtouch transitions is not going to go well at all.

Think of it as just a hidden element that animates into view. Just like any other web page element on an old school site!